# How to edit "Local Path" inside "Deployment Manager"?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

Some Delphi projects have non-default deployment path. And it is not editable using "Deployment Manager". Is there any way to change "Local Path"? (using "Deployment Manager" or not)

For example, I want to change "bin\" to "Win32\Release\"

Comment: There's no way (at present) to edit the local path. Remove them from the deployment, then re-add them from the location they're in.

Comment: @DaveNottage I can't even remove it. There must be a way!

Comment: If you cannot remove an entry, it's because it's one that is automatic, which should not be edited/removed anyway. Which one(s) are you referring to?